# Create reusable chart style in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, styles

I would like to be able to change the formatting of groups of reports separately from the content of the report itself. Then if we decide to change the way we present our reports this can be changed in one central style type sheet or something similar. Is this easy to do? Is reporting services capable of this or am I using the wrong tool?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, the closest thing I have found is an elegant work around explained [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-with-style/) using expressions that reference results a database. Not an ideal solution, and I think I will be using a different tool, perhaps a custom web application using a pre made .net chart object, like MSChart.

Answer (score 0):

That depend on what you mean by the formatting of reports. You can access and change the report manager and report toolbar style sheets. But the actual report formatting is not controlled by css. You could also embed the reports in a custom website but they would still render pretty much the same as they did in the Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Comment: That would mean individually changing each report if a formatting requirement changed, which is unacceptable for the requirements I have.